# Internal server error on Azure deployed web app

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have deployed an web app to Azure server but when I open my website it gives me error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

In browser console the error are

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)
aspapireact.azurewebsites.net/:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)

I did all the changes required to deploy app on Azure like 
connection string in appsettings, 
API url in all pages, 
Allow access to other resource for Azure SQL DB
connection string in configuration in Azure app service setting

Now I don't know what to do and where should I do changes

this is link for my project on git

https://github.com/rlbrs/ASPAPIReact

this one has all localhost connection but in Azure I have made required changes

Connection string - tcp:aspapireact.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=ReactTask;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=rlbrs;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;

API URL - https://aspapireact.azurewebsites.net/api/Customers

It say URL module error do I have to make changes in my DB Context.cs file

```
namespace RahulTask1.Model
{
public class DatabaseContext: DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Store> Store { get; set; }
}
}
```

Web Config file from azure/server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
          modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
           <aspNetCore processPath=".\RahulTask1.exe" 
           stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\? 
           \%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
   </system.webServer>
   </location>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: Why do you think `URL Rewrite Module ` has anything to do with database and dbcontext. Its entirely different thing that comes into play even before your app even get executed. Check the IIS config, web config and such for any url rewrite configuration problem like invalid syntax or such.

Comment: In visual studio there is no web config file but its in Azure app on server. I have added that in question